# Delete Multiple Views

Tags: maintenance

I currently delete a view by selecting it -> "Modify View" -> "Delete".

I would like to delete 10 or so Views on the same List, does anyone know a way of deleting multiple views of a list all in one shot?

No Sharepoint Designer, must be strictly out of the box SharePoint 2010.

Comment: can you use the javascript csom ?

Comment: @MdMazzotti Great Thought! However I am restricted to using solely the controls available from within my site ie. "Site Settings", "List Tools"...No outside Software.

Comment: the javascript csom is built in, no need to do anything special. If you press F12 and open up the javascript console, you can send commands right from there.

Comment: @MdMazzotti Coool! but unfortunately I do not have the scripting knowledge to know what to do :( +1 for pointing this out to me.  Worth some reading! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible, but you can use the javascript csom to accomplish this.
Here's an example:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var listCollection = web.get_lists();
var list = listCollection.getByTitle("MyList");
var viewCollection = list.get_views();

var view = viewCollection.getByTitle("MyView");

view.deleteObject();
view.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    console.log('view deleted');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Just repeat for all the views you need to delete (a better way would be to write an async loop, but I don't want to complicate this more)

Comment: You should remove view.update(); to delete correctly your view

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably sure that using only OOB functionality that is the only way to do it. In fact, I think the only thing you can delete multiple of at a time is list items/documents.

Comment: I fear you may be correct, I will leave this open a while longer before accepting your answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Library for which you want to delete the view.
2. Click on Library Tab and go to Library Settings; click on that one and in the bottom you should see the list of your views.
3. Select (click) on the one that you are looking for and in the next page, click Delete

Comment: How will this help deleting multiple views at once?

Answer (score 0):

Please use SharePoint designer to select the 'view' that you want to delete and then select 'delete' option from the top ribbon.

Comment: Please re-read the question. Designer is not an available tool.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

1. Open a library in the same site and then open it in the Explorer View.
2. Go back one level up in the Explorer view, find a folder called Lists.
3. Open the lists folder, you will find folders with the list names.
4. Open the folder with the list name you want to delete multiple views.
5. Find the views and delete them from the Explorer view.

Make sure you do not delete the default view, nor the system-generated views.